# Data transformation in R

Tags: r, transform

I am looking for an R example for transforming a dataframe.
I have a dataframe with 100 rows ( 2 rows per US state)

```
     Status  State Count 
     default    AK   15
     nodefault  AK   71
     default    AL   56
     nodefault  AL  428
     default    AR   33
     nodefault  AR  228
     default    AZ  132
     nodefault  AZ  801
     ......
     ......
```

My desired transformation is a dataframe with 50 rows:

```
      State Count1  Count2 
        AK   15       71
        AL   56      428
        AR   33      228
        AZ  132      801
       ....
```

Could you suggest any R function to do this transformation?

I tried to use the 'aggregate'  function. However, it expects a parameter such as: 'mean' OR 'Sum', and I do not want mean or sum.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few possibilities:

**1) xtabs**

```
> xtabs(Count ~ State + Status, DF)
     Status
State default nodefault
   AK      15        71
   AL      56       428
   AR      33       228
   AZ     132       801
```

**2) tapply**

```
> tapply(DF[[3]], DF[2:1], c)
     Status
State default nodefault
   AK      15        71
   AL      56       428
   AR      33       228
   AZ     132       801
```

**3) reshape**

```
> reshape(data = DF, dir = "wide", idvar = "State", timevar = "Status")
  State Count.default Count.nodefault
1    AK            15              71
3    AL            56             428
5    AR            33             228
7    AZ           132             801
```

`dcast` in the reshape2 package is another possibility that works somewhat like `reshape`.

**4) read.zoo**

```
> library(zoo)
>
> read.zoo(DF, index = "State", split = "Status", FUN = identity)
   default nodefault
AK      15        71
AL      56       428
AR      33       228
AZ     132       801
```

**5) split/merge**

```
> do.call("merge", c(unname(split(DF, DF$Status)), by = 2))[c(-2, -4)]
  State Count.x Count.y
1    AK      15      71
2    AL      56     428
3    AR      33     228
4    AZ     132     801
```

This could also be expressed as:

```
s <- split(DF, DF$Status)
merge(s[[1]], s[[2]], by = 2)[c(-2, -4)]
```

or

```
with(split(DF, DF$Status), merge(default, nodefault, by = 2))[c(-2, -4)]
```

*ADDED* solution 5.

Answer (score 3):

Use the dcast function from the reshape2 package

```
require(reshape2)
DB2 <- dcast(DB, State ~ Status, value.var="Count")
colnames(DB2) <- c("State", "Count1", "Count2")
```

Comment: you might need to rename the columns too.

Comment: Right I forgott. Thanks!